# How do I display records in the same row although I am using group by on 2 columns that appear in different rows right now?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

[This is the output I am getting now but I want all the records for one gateway in one row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leLrH.png) I am trying to find the damage count and total count of packages processed by an airport in a week. Currently I am grouping by airport and week so I am getting the records in different rows for an airport and week. I want to have the records for a particular airport in a single row with weeks being in the same row.

I tried putting a conditional group by but that did not work.

```
select tmp.gateway,tmp.weekbucket, sum(tmp.damaged_count) as DamageCount, sum(tmp.total_count) as TotalCount, round(sum(tmp.DPMO),0) as DPMO from
  (
    select a.gateway, 
    date_trunc('week', (a.processing_date + interval '1 day')) - interval '1 day' as weekbucket,
    count(distinct(b.fulfillment_shipment_id||b.package_id)) as damaged_count, 
    count(distinct(a.fulfillment_shipment_id||a.package_id)) as total_count, 
    count(distinct(b.fulfillment_shipment_id||b.package_id))*1.00/count(distinct(a.Fulfillment_Shipment_id || a.package_id))*1000000 as DPMO
    from booker.d_air_shipments_na a
    left join trex.d_ps_packages b
    on (a.fulfillment_shipment_id||a.package_id =b.Fulfillment_Shipment_id||b.package_id)
    where a.processing_date >= current_date-7
    and (exception_summary in ('Reprint-Damaged Label') or exception_summary IS NULL)
    and substring(route, position(a.gateway IN route) +6, 1) <> 'K'
    group by a.gateway, weekbucket) as tmp
  group by tmp.gateway, tmp.weekbucket
  order by tmp.gateway, tmp.weekbucket desc;
```

Comment: Some sample data would go a long way.

Answer (score 0):

As you get two week's days starting and ending  hence its likely that youll get 2 rows for each. Can try to remove week bucket from group by after performing your actual select/within the inner select and put a max on week bucket with summing both counts of both start and end of week dates.

```
    select 
         tmp.gateway,max(tmp.weekbucket), 
            sum(tmp.damaged_count) as 
           DamageCount, 
          sum(tmp.total_count) as TotalCount, 
          round(sum(tmp.DPMO),0) as DPMO 
         from
        (
    select a.gateway, 
    date_trunc('week', (a.processing_date + 
     interval '1 day')) - interval '1 day' as 
       weekbucket,   count(distinct(b.fulfillment_shipment_id||b 
       .package_id)) as damaged_count, 
  count(distinct(a.fulfillment_shipment_id||a    .package_id)) as total_count, 
    count(distinct(b.fulfillment_shipment_id||b.package_id))*1.00/count(distinct(a.Fulfillment_Shipment_id || a.package_id))*1000000 as DPMO
    from booker.d_air_shipments_na a
    left join trex.d_ps_packages b
    on (a.fulfillment_shipment_id||a.package_id =b.Fulfillment_Shipment_id||b.package_id)
    where a.processing_date >= current_date-7
    and (exception_summary in ('Reprint-Damaged Label') or exception_summary IS NULL)
    and substring(route, position(a.gateway IN route) +6, 1) <> 'K'
    group by a.gateway, weekbucket) as tmp
  group by tmp.gateway
  order by tmp.gateway, 
   max(tmp.weekbucket) desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to pivot the two weeks into a single row with two sets of aggregates?:

```
select
    tmp.gateway,
    tmp.weekbucket,
    min(case when rn = 1 then tmp.damaged_count end) as DamageCountWeek1,
    min(case when rn = 2 then tmp.damaged_count end) as DamageCountWeek2,
    min(case when rn = 1 then tmp.total_count end) as TotalCountWeek1,
    min(case when rn = 2 then tmp.total_count end) as TotalCountWeek2,
    min(case when rn = 1 then round(tmp.DPMO, 0) end) as DPMOWeek1,
    min(case when rn = 2 then round(tmp.DPMO, 0) end) as DPMOWeek2,
from (
    select row_number() over (partition by gateway order by weekbucket) as rn,
    ...
) as tmp
group by tmp.gateway
order by tmp.gateway;
```

Comment: Yes, I want to pivot the two weeks with 2 set of aggregates in a single row. How do I use the above query to do that

Comment: @Sankalp You add back the rest of your inner query where I put in an ellipsis (...).

Comment: added the code from (select a.gateway......group by a.gateway, weekbucket) in place of (...) in your code but it throws an error

Comment: I see that I missed a few closing parentheses. Give that a try.

Comment: I added the code and removed the , at the end of your outer query. It throws an error 'aggregate function calls may not have nested aggregate or window function;'.

Comment: I removed the `sum()` operations in the outer query. Hopefully that was the last issue.